# (JS) Enable Button during a certain period of time in a day

Tags: javascript, button, time

I've been trying to enable a button only in a certain period of time in a day, but I can't make it work..

What I've been trying to do:
The button should be enabled from 17:00 o'clock to 22:00 o'clock (GMT +1).
I wrote my script with the aid of sites where people were requesting a similar system, but I can't make it work.. I  hope that you can help me

**Sorry for my english^^**

Here is the script:

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktime" value="Check"/>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
var enableDisable = function(){
var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
if ((UTC_hours == 17) && (UTC_hours == 18) && (UTC_hours == 19) && (UTC_hours == 20) && (UTC_hours == 21) && (UTC_hours == 22)){
document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = true;
}
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: FWIW Don't forget to protect the backend as well.

Comment: @VisioN Never did javascript before, so I got no clue what u're talkin about :P

Comment: @user3174114 javascript is a client sided language, meaning a user can alter/edit it as they please. If you rely on the button being disabled for security reasons, make sure you validate the time as well on the server side (php, ruby, c#, whatever you're using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had missing brackets and your id was wrong, this should work.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktime" value="Check"/>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
var enableDisable = function(){
    var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
    if (UTC_hours > 16 && UTC_hours < 22){
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = true;
    }
};
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Realized that with the id.. edited my first post, but I guess it was a little bit too late :)

Comment: How do I use this for GMT+5.30 (India)? Like This:  Date().getUTCHours() +5.3?

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement isn't going to work like that; you're testing if the hour is 17 AND 18 AND 19 AND..., which is obviously never going to be the case as it can't be all of those hours at once.  It should be:

```
if (UTC_hours > 16 && UTC_hours < 22)
```

That will ensure that it's at least 5pm, but before 10pm.

Comment: Okay, I've changed that IF-statement but still it doesn't seem to work correctly. 

In order to check whether your tip works, I switched disabled = false to disabled = true (and the other way around).
When I tested the new javascript, the button was not disabled but still active. (which should be not the case since I switched false to true)